# Connecting More than 32 USB Devices using USB 2 Port & ECHI

Tags: 20.04, usb, usb-drive, lsusb

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 system (Intel 2400K, ASRock Z68 Extreme3 Gen3) with two [90W powered 16-port USB 3 hubs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KHRLSTT) connected to two **USB 2** ports on the motherboard. There are 16 external USB 3 drives connected to the first USB hub, and will have soon have 16 external USB 3 drives connected to the second USB 3 hub.

When the hubs are both connected to two **USB 3** ports, `dmesg` shows the log message

> xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 32.

Switching both hubs to two **USB 2** ports avoids this error message.

Is the 32 device limit still there? `lsusb` shows these devices connected using `ehci` instead of `xchi`?

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 98, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 99, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 109, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 101, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 114, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 104, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 100, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 103, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
                    |__ Port 1: Dev 108, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 115, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 106, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
                    |__ Port 1: Dev 112, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 110, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
                    |__ Port 1: Dev 116, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 102, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 107, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 113, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 118, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 120, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 105, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 119, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 111, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 121, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 117, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 65, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 69, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 66, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 97, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 96, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 71, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 67, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

Comment: [This article](https://acroname.com/blog/how-many-usb-devices-can-i-connect) may be of some interest to you. It seems to be a hardware limitation.

Comment: I think switching to the motherboard's USB 2 ports makes the hub and its connected devices using ECHI? If so, does this mean the 32 device limitation is no longer there for my system?

Comment: As explained in the article I linked to, it's a limitation with some xhci controllers, and forcing USB2 allows you more devices, yet at a lower speed.